# change url of current page to link to french version

Tags: php, url

I am building a client site with english and french versions.

On the english pages, I'd like users to be able to click a 'french version' link that would automatically take them to the french version OF THAT PAGE.

So if my url structure is like this:

http://mysite.com/en/page-name

I'd like the 'french version' link to point to:

http://mysite.com/fr/page-name

Can someone please offer me the php to take the current page url, and substitute the /en/ for /fr/ in the link code? I know this is probably something very simple, but I'm a php newb.

Answer (score 4):

In your page template or rendering just use this for your link. Assume the current language is stored in a variable called $current_lang. At the top of your page add this code (it doesn't have to be at the top, just somewhere before you try to use the link):

```
<?php
$french_link = str_replace("/$current_lang/",  '/fr/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
?>
```

Now just use $french_link as your link to that page. So in your anchor link use this:

```
<a href="<?php echo $french_link; ?>">French Version</a>
```

Note that most servers have PHP "short tags" enabled so you could use this for your link:

```
<a href="<?= $french_link; ?>">French Version</a>
```

The <?= syntax is just shorthand for <?php echo. I personally prefer this syntax, but there are many on the other side who have good reasons for not using it. See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use) for details.

Comment: Thanks for the understanding @davidethell, but I don't understand.  I guess what I meant to say is that I'm a TOTAL newb.  Should the HTML in my template look like this?:

`<a href="<?php $french_link = str_replace("/$current_lang/",  '/fr/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
 ?>">french version</a>`

Comment: To add to that, I already (literally) have a page on the  site with url:
http://mysite.com/fr/page-name

I just want to make it easier on the user to go directly to the french version of the page they are on, rather than just have the 'french version' link point to the homepage of the french version.

Kapishe?

Comment: @themav, I edited my answer to help answer your followup question.